# Angular 6: Unable to increase mobile performance in Google pagespeed insights

Tags: angular, angular6

I want to increase **mobile performance** in "https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/" for my **angular 6 web application**.

I have tried the following things to increase performance of my site:
**1)** ng build --prod (AOT and build optimize enabled) 
**2)** Gzip enabled 
**3)** Image optimization
**4)** Increased cache for images

I expect the output 40% out of 100%, but the actual output is 5%

Comment: This is a very broad question.. Use brotli compression, pre-fetch critical css, revise your node package, etc

Comment: Have a look at the performance improvements suggested in the audit

Comment: @David, Yes I have looked into suggestion but I can't reduce my code further

Comment: @wentjun gzip is already enabled so I think there is no need for brotli compression, pre-fetch critical css will reduce my loading speed and my project is running on dist folder and all packages which are installed is used in my project and there are no extra packages installed.